# Is there a dictionary feature in VIM

Tags: vim, gvim, dictionary

I use vim for pretty much all my typing work. I was wondering if there was a feature that would use an offline dictionary and whenever I typed

`:def Ubuntu`

It would give me the definition of the requested word in a new buffer, or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about an actual definition but I know that you can make it auto-complete by giving you drop down list of keywords while your typing.  Along with this option there is also a thesaurus option to bring up other versions of the word you are typing.

You must first download an offsite dictionary file and have Vim point to it by using the `set:` command.  I have provided a link that will better describe how to go about doing this in better detail

http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Dictionary_completions

Comment: Yes, I am aware of the auto-complete feature. Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

This project uses stardict to provide definitions in a separate buffer: https://github.com/phongvcao/vim-stardict